# What is the remainder when 4 to the power 1000 is divided by 7

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

What is the remainder when $4^{1000}$ is divided by 7?
In my book the problem is solved, but I am unable to understand the approach. Please help me understand -

> Solution  -
>
> To find the Cyclicity, we keep finding the remainders until any
>   remainder repeats itself. It can be understood with the following
>   example:
>
> No./7    ->    $4^1$  $4^2$  $4^3$  $4^4$  $4^5$  $4^6$  $4^7$  $4^8$
>
> Remainder -> 4 2 1 4 2 1 4 2
>
> Now $4^4$ gives us the same remainder as $4^1$, so the Cyclicity is of
>   3 (Because remainders start repeating themselves after $4^3$
>
> So any power of 3 or multiple of 3 will give the remainder of 1. So,
>   $4^{999}$ will give remainder 1.
>
> Final remainder is 4.

**Now I don't understand the last line. Please explain, how the remainder comes down to 4?**

Comment: You have seen (by example, not really proved), that
$$4^k \equiv 4^l \mod 7 \Leftrightarrow k\equiv l \mod 3$$
Chose $k=1000, l=1$ and you are done.

Comment: If in doubt, try the very basic things. You know that $4^{999}=7r+1$ for some integer $r$. Multiply by $4$ to give $4^{1000}=28r+4$ which clearly leaves remainder $4$ on division by $7$.

Comment: I didn't understand the answers or comments with "mod", what are they?

Comment: I got it. I did searched the forum, and came o know about Fermat's little theorem, which solves these kind of problems. Thanks everyone, I got it.

Comment: @Man_From_India $x\equiv y \mod z$ - where mod is short for "modulo" (sometimes "modulus") is another way of saying that $z$ is a factor of $x-y$ or alternatively that $x=rz+y$ for some integer $r$. It takes a bit of getting used to, but is very useful, particularly because (with a little care) you can do arithmetic $\mod z$ and forget that there are terms like $rz$ in the background.

Answer (score 4):

${\rm mod}\ 7\!:\ \color{#c00}{4^{\large 3}\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, 4^{\large 1000}\equiv 4^{\large 1+999}\equiv 4 (\color{#c00}{4^{\large 3}})^{\large 333}\equiv 4\color{#c00}{(1)}^{\large 333}\equiv 4$

More generally we have that $\ 4^{\large r+3q}\equiv 4^r (\color{#c00}{4^{\large 3}})^{\large q}\equiv 4^{\large r}\color{#c00}{(1)}^{\large q}\equiv 4^{\large r}$

Written in terms of mod this is: $\ 4^{\large n}\equiv 4^{\large n\ {\rm mod}\ 3}\,$ where $\ n = 3q+r\,$ and $\,r = n\ {\rm mod}\ 3$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $2^3\equiv1\mod7$, and $4=2^2$.

Answer (score 1):

As you have said, the remainders are cyclic in the pattern 4 2 1 4 2 1.
So, if $4^{999}$ has a remainder of 1, $4^{1000}$ will have the next remainder in the cycle which is 4.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\varphi(7)=6$, therefore, $4^6\equiv 1\  (\mathrm{mod}\ 7)$ by Euler's theorem. Now, $ (4^6)^{166}=4^{996}\equiv 1\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 7)$. Since $4^4\equiv 4\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 7)$, it follows that $4^{1000}=4^{996}\times 4^4\equiv 4\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 7)$.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for the answer. The OP [commented](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735217/what-is-the-remainder-when-4-to-the-power-1000-is-divided-by-7#comment1533973_735217) about learning about [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), and there are other answers that are along the same lines. Since none of the other answers mentioned Fermat's Little Theorem, if you mentioned that and added a link to it, your answer would have a bit more value.